# Why is my .c file not recognizing my header file? 2 errors, XCode

Tags: c, xcode, struct, header

My header file:

```
#ifndef __FRACTION_H__

#define __FRACTION_H__

struct fraction{
    int wholeNumber;
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};

struct fraction fractionCreate(int numerator, int denominator);
struct fraction fractionAdd(struct fraction a, struct fraction b);
struct fraction fractionSubtract(struct fraction a, struct fraction b);
struct fraction fractionMultiply(struct fraction a, struct fraction b);
struct fraction fractionDivide(struct fraction a, struct fraction b);
void fractionPrint(struct fraction f);

#endif
```

The 2 errors i keep getting in my .c file are:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main", referenced from:
implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

my .c file

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fraction.h"

struct fraction fractionCreate(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    struct fraction result;
    result.wholeNumber = 0;
    if (denominator == 0)
    {
        result.numerator = 0;
        result.denominator = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (numerator*denominator <0)
        {

            int tempNumerator = fabs(numerator);
            int tempDenominator = fabs(denominator);
            int temp = 0;
            while(tempDenominator != 0)
            {
                temp = tempDenominator;
                tempDenominator = tempNumerator%tempDenominator;
                tempNumerator = temp;
            }
            int GCD = tempNumerator;

            numerator = fabs(numerator);
            denominator = fabs(denominator);
            //Num is larger than denom
            if(numerator>=denominator)
            {
                //whole number
                if(numerator%denominator == 0)
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = (numerator/denominator)*-1;
                    result.numerator = 1;
                    result.denominator = 1;
                }
                //mixed number
                else
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = ((numerator - (numerator%denominator)) /denominator)*-1;
                    numerator = (numerator%denominator);
                    if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator/GCD;
                        result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator;
                        result.denominator = denominator;
                    }
                }
            }

            //simple fraction
            else
            {
                if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                {
                    result.numerator = (numerator/GCD)*-1;
                    result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.numerator = numerator*-1;
                    result.denominator = denominator;
                }
            }
        }

        else if (numerator*denominator > 0)
        {
            int tempNumerator = fabs(numerator);
            int tempDenominator = fabs(denominator);
            int temp = 0;
            while(tempDenominator != 0)
            {
                temp = tempDenominator;
                tempDenominator = tempNumerator%tempDenominator;
                tempNumerator = temp;
            }
            int GCD = tempNumerator;
            numerator = fabs(numerator);
            denominator = fabs(denominator);

            //Num is larger than denom
            if(numerator>=denominator)
            {
                //whole number
                if(numerator%denominator == 0)
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = numerator/denominator;
                    result.numerator = 1;
                    result.denominator = 1;
                }
                //mixed number
                else
                {
                    result.wholeNumber = (numerator - (numerator%denominator)) /denominator;
                    numerator = (numerator%denominator);
                    if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator/GCD;
                        result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.numerator = numerator;
                        result.denominator = denominator;
                    }
                }
            }

            //simple fraction
            else
            {
                if (numerator%GCD ==0 && denominator%GCD ==0)
                {
                    result.numerator = numerator/GCD;
                    result.denominator= denominator/GCD;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.numerator = numerator;
                    result.denominator = denominator;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void fractionPrint(struct fraction f)
{
    if (f.numerator == 0 && f.denominator == 0)
    {
        printf("Divide by zero!\n");
    }
    else if(f.numerator ==0 && f.denominator !=0)
    {
        printf("0\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // There IS a whole number
        if (f.wholeNumber !=0)
        {
            //ONLY whole number
            if (f.numerator == 1 && f.denominator ==1 )
            {
                printf("%d\n", f.wholeNumber);
            }
            //Mixed number
            else
            {
                printf("%d %d/%d\n", f.wholeNumber, f.numerator, f.denominator);
            }
        }
        //fraction only
        else
        {
            printf("%d/%d\n", f.numerator, f.denominator);
        }
    }

}




struct fraction fractionAdd(struct fraction a, struct fraction b)
{
    struct fraction result;

    //If whole number exists
    if(a.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (a.numerator ==1 && a.denominator ==1)
        {
            a.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    else if (b.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (b.numerator ==1 && b.denominator ==1)
        {
            b.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    //If the numerator of a is 1 and denom is 1, then make it 0
    //If the numerator of b is 1 and deom is 1, then make it 0

    //Open up the mixed fraction
    a.numerator = (a.wholeNumber*a.denominator) + a.numerator;
    b.numerator = (b.wholeNumber*b.denominator) + b.numerator;

    //If the denominators equal
    if (a.denominator == b.denominator)
    {
        result.numerator = a.numerator + b.numerator;
        result.denominator = b.denominator;
        result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);
        return result;
    }
    else if (a.denominator == 0 && b.denominator == 0)
    {
    }
    //If the denominator is not equal,
    else if (a.denominator != b.denominator)
    {
        int LCM;
        int temp =0;
        //only use the absolute values when finding the GCD
        int tempDenominatorA = fabs(a.denominator);
        int tempDenominatorB = fabs(b.denominator);

        while(tempDenominatorB!=0)
        {
            temp = tempDenominatorB;
            tempDenominatorB = tempDenominatorA%tempDenominatorB;
            tempDenominatorA = temp;
        }
        int GCD = tempDenominatorA;
        LCM = fabs(a.denominator*b.denominator)/GCD;

        //then multiply each denominator and numerator by a number that will make it the LCM
        int multiplyA, multiplyB;
        multiplyA = LCM/fabs(a.denominator);
        multiplyB = LCM/fabs(b.denominator);
        a.numerator = a.numerator*multiplyA;
        b.numerator = b.numerator*multiplyB;

        result.numerator = a.numerator + b.numerator;
        result.denominator = LCM;

        result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);

        return result;

    }

    return result;
}

struct fraction fractionSubtract(struct fraction a, struct fraction b)
{
    struct fraction result;

    //If whole number exists
    if(a.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (a.numerator ==1 && a.denominator ==1)
        {
            a.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    else if (b.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (b.numerator ==1 && b.denominator ==1)
        {
            b.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    //If the numerator of a is 1 and denom is 1, then make it 0
    //If the numerator of b is 1 and deom is 1, then make it 0

    //Open up the mixed fraction
    a.numerator = (a.wholeNumber*a.denominator) + a.numerator;
    b.numerator = (b.wholeNumber*b.denominator) + b.numerator;
    a.wholeNumber = 0;
    b.wholeNumber = 0;

    //If the denominators equal
    if (a.denominator == b.denominator)
    {
        result.numerator = a.numerator - b.numerator;
        result.denominator = b.denominator;
        result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);
        return result;
    }
    else if (a.denominator == 0 && b.denominator == 0)
    {
    }
    //If the denominator is not equal,
    else if (a.denominator != b.denominator)
    {
        int LCM;
        int temp =0;
        //only use the absolute values when finding the GCD
        int tempDenominatorA = fabs(a.denominator);
        int tempDenominatorB = fabs(b.denominator);

        while(tempDenominatorB!=0)
        {
            temp = tempDenominatorB;
            tempDenominatorB = tempDenominatorA%tempDenominatorB;
            tempDenominatorA = temp;
        }
        int GCD = tempDenominatorA;
        LCM = fabs(a.denominator*b.denominator)/GCD;

        //then multiply each denominator and numerator by a number that will make it the LCM
        int multiplyA, multiplyB;
        multiplyA = LCM/fabs(a.denominator);
        multiplyB = LCM/fabs(b.denominator);
        a.numerator = a.numerator*multiplyA;
        b.numerator = b.numerator*multiplyB;

        result.numerator = a.numerator - b.numerator;
        result.denominator = LCM;

        result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);

        return result;

    }

    return result;
}

struct fraction fractionMultiply(struct fraction a, struct fraction b)
{
    struct fraction result;
    //If whole number exists
    if(a.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (a.numerator ==1 && a.denominator ==1)
        {
            a.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    else if (b.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (b.numerator ==1 && b.denominator ==1)
        {
            b.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    //If the numerator of a is 1 and denom is 1, then make it 0
    //If the numerator of b is 1 and deom is 1, then make it 0

    //Open up the mixed fraction
    a.numerator = (a.wholeNumber*a.denominator) + a.numerator;
    b.numerator = (b.wholeNumber*b.denominator) + b.numerator;

    a.wholeNumber = 0;
    b.wholeNumber = 0;

    result.numerator = a.numerator*b.numerator;
    result.denominator = a.denominator*b.denominator;

    result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);

    return result;
}

struct fraction fractionDivide(struct fraction a, struct fraction b)
{
    struct fraction result;
    //If whole number exists
    if(a.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (a.numerator ==1 && a.denominator ==1)
        {
            a.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    else if (b.wholeNumber!=0)
    {
        if (b.numerator ==1 && b.denominator ==1)
        {
            b.numerator =0;
        }
    }
    //If the numerator of a is 1 and denom is 1, then make it 0
    //If the numerator of b is 1 and deom is 1, then make it 0

    //Open up the mixed fraction
    a.numerator = (a.wholeNumber*a.denominator) + a.numerator;
    b.numerator = (b.wholeNumber*b.denominator) + b.numerator;

    a.wholeNumber = 0;
    b.wholeNumber = 0;

    result.numerator = a.numerator*b.denominator;
    result.denominator = a.denominator*b.numerator;

    result = fractionCreate(result.numerator, result.denominator);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: where is your `main()`?

Comment: It's for a class assignment so the online program that checks our code will add the main in

Comment: uh ho!! **class assignment**. how come i did not see that coming?

Comment: the error messages are because there is no main() function and the linker automatically includes the start function, which is trying to call the main() function.  Those errors 'should' go away when the code is part of the instructors' project with a main() function.

Answer (score 1):

you .c file is missing the main()

the  gcc or any othe c compiler first looks for the main() in the program (.c file )

it seem to me that you are missing the main() in your .c file

try adding a main() in your .c file and call other functions inside the main function in the order that you wanted